# Cassandra JDBC preparedstatment error

Tags: java, jdbc, cassandra

I have a following cassandra table "users" defined in keyspace "chemdb"

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  userid text PRIMARY KEY,
  passwd text,
  fname text,
  lname text,
  creationdate timestamp,  
  isactive text  
);
```

I created a java class `JDBConnec.java` to connect jsp with cassandra using jdbc:

```
package dbclasses;

    import java.sql.*;
    import java.lang.*;
    import java.io.*;   

     public class JDBConnec {

           public Statement stmt=null;     
           public ResultSet rs=null;   
           public Connection con=null;

       public PreparedStatement pstmt = null;


        public JDBConnec()
        {

        try
        {
            Class.forName("org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:cassandra://127.0.0.1:9160/chemdb","okkkkk","12345");   
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());         
        }
       }
    }
```

The above class is succesfully compiling.

However in my jsp file, when I use the following code to select record from database by using Preparedstatements, I get the below mentioned error:

```
JDBConnec db = new JDBConnec();
String query = "select * from users where userid=?";
db.pstmt = db.con.prepareStatement(query); 
db.pstmt.setString(1, "henry");
db.rs = db.pstmt.executeQuery();
```

It gives following error

```
InvalidRequestException(why:Undefined name userid in where clause ('userid EQ ?'))
```

Does cassandra jdbc driver support preparedstatments in jsp? Any thoughts on why this error is occuring. Thanks in advance.

Cassandra version: 2.0.8
Java: 7
Apache tomcat: latest downloaded yesterday

Comment: What's with single quotes in 'henry'? It's should be "henry" rather.

Comment: sorry, that i mistakenly put while copy-pasting code here. In code I used a string variable.

Comment: Looks like userid is not recognized. Make sure userid is exactly the column you are looking for in database.

Comment: It was query problem. I changed the query and removed asterisk, and it worked fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out problem. I just changed the query from

```
String query = "select * from users where userid=?";
```

to

```
String query = "select userid, passwd from chemdb.users where userid=?";
```

and it worked fine.

Thanks!